# Trimble MAPS routing API - trouble using avoids and favors

Tags: trimble-maps

I am using PC*MILER Web Services REST service route reports, but avoids and favors are both being ignored.

URL:

```
https://pcmiler.alk.com/apis/rest/v1.0/Service.svc/route/routeReports?dataVersion=PCM30
```

Body:

```
{
                "ReportRoutes": [{
                                "RouteId": "562595",
                                "Stops": [{
                                                "Coords": {
                                                                "Lat": "41.483611",
                                                                "Lon": "-83.354120"
                                                }
                                },
                                {
                                                "Coords": {
                                                                "Lat": "41.326000",
                                                                "Lon": "-82.622300"
                                                }
                                }],
                                "Options": {
                                                "UseAvoidsAndFavors": true,
                                                "AFSetIDs": [-1],
                                                "BordersOpen": false,
                                                "DistanceUnits": 0,
                                                "FerryDiscourage": true,
                                                "HighwayOnly": true,
                                                "OverrideRestrict": false,
                                                "RouteOpt": 0,
                                                "RoutingType": 1
                                },
                                "ReportTypes": [{
                                                "__type": "CalculateMilesReportType:http:\/\/pcmiler.alk.com\/APIs\/v1.0"
                                }]
                }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that this returning a warning: "Warning: 199 Route at index 0: RouteOptions.AFSetIDs is unavailable in previous versions of PCMiler Web Services.,199 Route at index 0: Unlicensed for Avoids & Favors"

This is due to passing the parameter "useAvoidFavors", which is the former legacy PC*MILER Web Service. Removing that resolves the issue. Only the following parameter is required: AFSetIDs": [-1]